# CMake target to just compile a source file

Tags: c++, cmake, compilation, header-only

I am writing a header-only library using C++17. I would like to include it in a "dummy" source file:

```cpp
#include "my/library.h"
// EOF
```

The purpose is to ensure the library properly includes all of its dependencies. I also want to run static analyzers on it and compile it with as many compiler checks enabled as is practical.

To create a normal executable target I need to add the `main()` function, otherwise the linking stage will fail.
I guess I can also create a static library target, which should work correctly, although it will create an artifact I do not need.

Is there any other alternative?

Comment: Even if you create a library, you have to load it from a program that has a main (or loaded from another library which will be loaded by an exec who has a main function). I don't understand your question

Comment: Maybe just add unit tests, so library gets compiled as side effect.

Comment: I need to verify that the code in the library: a) has no missing includes, b) compiles cleanly and without warnings, c) passes static analysis. None of these checks requires building an executable.

Comment: I do have unit tests. In fact, I develop the library in TDD with tight red-green-refactor cycles. I do not want compilation as a side effect. I want it as a (almost) sole purpose and this is why I want a separate target.

Comment: @KrzysiekKarbowiak But in this case, how about : linking errors ? If you don't link binaries, how are you going to check for link errors?

Comment: @Landstalker: thanks for your interest in this topic. Linking errors are things to check as well, but are different kind of issues and are out of scope of my question. I will tackle them separately.

Comment: Why is this tagged with CMake? Are you using CMake to manage your buildsystem generation? Not sure how this fits in with the question..

Comment: @squareskittles: Yes, I am using CMake for buildsystem generation and build itself. For convenience, on all the platforms that I use (currently Linux and Windows) i just do: `cmake --build .`.

Comment: You could tell CMake to build this into an [Object library](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html#object-libraries), essentially just the `.o` or `.obj` object file. Use this: `add_library(MyObj OBJECT library.cpp)`, where `library.cpp` is your dummy source file.

Comment: @squareskittles: Thanks! I was not aware of the Object library and this looks like it might be it.

Comment: Wrote up a quick answer showing the usage for `OBJECT` targets. The documentation has further examples as well. Hope that is helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CMake can create a simple [Object](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html#object-libraries) library, which will only be a `.o` or `.obj` file:

> The `OBJECT` library type defines a non-archival collection of object files resulting from compiling the given source files.

To do this, use the `OBJECT` keyword with the [`add_library()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html#object-libraries) command:

```
add_library(MyObj OBJECT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/library.cpp)
target_include_directories(MyObj PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
```

You can later reference the object file(s) to be compiled into other libraries or executables:

```
add_library(MyLibrary STATIC 
    $<TARGET_OBJECTS:MyObj> 
    MyOtherSource.cpp 
    HelpersFunctions.cpp
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Most compilers allow you to override the default extension for input types. If you just pass `my/library.h` as the input file to the compiler, it can compile that into a `library.o` or `library.obj`.

Note that short of compiling an executable, you can't be sure that your `library.h` is complete. In particular, C++ requires that non-`inline` `static const` class members are defined exactly once per program if they're odr-used. So if you forget `inline` in your `library.h`, you might not notice this in your simple test. And even if you'd add an empty `main()`, that still wouldn't odr-use those members.